# Use Table Results to Query a Select Top 100 from (TABLE NAME from result)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE ColumnResults 
(
     TableName VARCHAR(60)
)
GO

INSERT INTO ColumnResults
    SELECT name 
    FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM syscolumns 
                 WHERE name like 'EmployeeID%')
    ORDER BY name

SELECT * FROM ColumnResults
```

I now want to take results set from `ColumnResults` and for each row use it to query the following:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
FROM (TABLE NAME FROM INITIAL RESULT SET or "ColumnResults" goes Here)
```

Continue doing for each result row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM ColumnResults

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

      select top 100 from @name

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use something like the below:

```
DROP TABLE #TableName

CREATE TABLE #TableName
(
    TableName VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #TableName 
(
    TableName
)

SELECT name FROM sys.objects
WHERE name LIKE 'employeeID%'

DECLARE @TableCount AS INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TableName)

WHILE @TableCount > 0

BEGIN 

DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(200) = (SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM #TableName)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @TableName + ''
--PRINT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)

SET @TableCount = @TableCount - 1

DELETE FROM #TableName WHERE TableName IN (SELECT TOP 1 TableName FROM #TableName )

END
```

Ensure you have the right schema in place of [dbo]. I also cant see you having a table name called employeeID. I think this would be a column in a table perhaps. So maybe just filter on Employee as a table name.